# Tf workspace does not exist error - what workspace is used when tf checkout command is used?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am experiencing a build problem which has started a few days ago and it still persists.
I am using Cake script and one of the steps is to checkout a folder and copy some dlls into that folder.

I am using the tf checkout /recusive command and I immediately get the following error:

```
The workspace ws_1_59;Project Collection Build Service (MM-RD) does not exist.
```

When I run the tf workspaces command the error is confirmed, indeed the ws_1_59 workspace does not exist.

My question is where is this workspace comming from? Is it cached or specified somewhere?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with corrupt cache (at least in my case).
I solved it by modifying the cake script to call:

```
tf workspaces /s:[project collection name]
```

That refreshed the build agent's cache and the build was a success aftewrwards.